# Is there a way for acts_as_flying_saucer to save a file without calling render_pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

As the title says I use the Rails gem that works good but I want to separately save pdf's to a folder. Is there a way to do this without calling render_pdf?

This is what does not work:

```
  render_pdf :template => 'caseprinttemplates/create_pdf_to_print.erb', :pdf_file => "/home/mattias/www/Inkasso/public/uploadedfiles/" + results[:title]

  redirect_to new_interventionreminder_path(:case_id => @interventionreminder.case_id, :saved => "1")
  return
```

This does work on another page:

```
render_pdf :template => 'caseprinttemplates/create_pdf_to_print.erb', :layout => nil, :send_file => { :filename => "samladutskrift.pdf"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acts_as_flying_saucer plugin is just a wrapper around the Flying Saucer java library.  In the source, you can see that only a single wrapper method is defined:  render_pdf().

https://github.com/dagi3d/acts_as_flying_saucer/blob/master/lib/acts_as_flying_saucer_controller.rb

You can, however, use render_pdf() to render to a file, like the examples found [here](https://github.com/dagi3d/acts_as_flying_saucer):

```
# Renders the template located at '/foo/bar/pdf.html.erb' and stores the pdf 
# in the temp path with a filename based on its md5 digest
render_pdf :file => '/foo/bar/pdf.html.erb'

# renders the template located at 'app/views/foo.html.erb' and saves the pdf
# in '/www/docs/foo.pdf'
render_pdf :template => 'foo', :pdf_file => '/www/docs/foo.pdf'

# renders the 'app/views/foo.html.erb' template, saves the pdf in the temp path
# and sends it to the browser with the name 'bar.pdf'
render_pdf :template => 'foo', :send_file => { :filename => 'bar.pdf' }
```

Comment: Thanks but I've tried all of those examples but I need something like this scenario: Save the file and redirect to another page. The funny thing is when I do this is that It complains on my meta tag that is written in a correct fashion because the page works on another page where I use the send_file option. Seems like the flying saucer lib is validating too which is good but when it complains about something that is not there or that is written correctly. I'll edit my code here to show you.

Comment: It works now. I needed a :layout => nil in the render_pdf. Saw that on the other page. Thanks for the help.